# P tag contents bleeding under a floating image

Tags: css

I have a list with each li having an image and then some text.

```
<div style="width:500px;">
<ul >
   <li>
       <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTyBPzjBIU0gCSFH7mLEVMuQ6d69KYfe14YCsJcLXCbHzhqJZ2p" width="100px" style ="float:left; ">

        <p>First line......<br/>Second: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
   </li>

</ul>
</div>
```

The problem is: If `p` contents extend beyond height of image, it flows to the left, under the image. How can I stop this? I want nothing below the image (in each `<li>`).

Thanks

Comment: That's the entire point of `float`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a left margin to your `p` elements:

```
​li p {
    margin-left: 105px;  /* width of your images */
}​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6zamg/1)

Answer (score 2):

Set `overflow: hidden;` on the `P` tags. The benefit of this method is that you don't need to know the width of the image tag.

```
li p {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

See **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6zamg/10/)**. I added 5 pixels of white space between the image and paragraph text, although that's optional.

Comment: Whoa. That's sweet. I've never seen that before.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of floating the image, you could float the p tag right and give it a width of 400px

Answer (score 0):

Just put a margin on the paragraph. Like this `p{margin-left:105px;}` Working example http://jsfiddle.net/xSbmn/

Keep the img floated left, and add a margin equal or larger than the img to the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You can float to the left, the image with a width of 100px and float to the right the parapgraph with a width of 400px.

Otherwise, it's much efficient to create a css file, to insert styles, and not write it on the html.